# Will selling part of an incomplete collections of knick knacks prevent me from completing the set quest?

Tags: god-of-war-2018

Eg lost and found toys, do I have to wait to complete the set before selling or can I sell them as I come across pieces of a collection and suffer no penalty to the rewards for completing the set or needing to buy back pieces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sell them.** You get the bonus XP once all pieces of a set are found, they don't have to all be in your inventory at once and they do nothing else for you besides grant you some hacksilver.